# (Environment) variable for current user's Jenkins API key?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a simple way of accessing the Jenkins API key (as described by [Authenticating scripted clients](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients)) of the user that invoked the script? I'm looking to pass it into the build script so that it can perform some maintenance operations back on Jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I never found one, I can say that it's safe to say that (as of May '12, at least) there isn't one.